# Column width style lose when converting .xls to csv

Tags: excel, csv, apache-poi, export-to-csv, xlsx

I am exporting an .xlsx document to .csv but I during that conversion I am loosing the complete style.  Column width style is loosing terribly I was using Mac OS Numbers app but If i remember it correctly same issue happened with Microsoft excel ( I do not have the windows machine to cross check that for the moment).

original excel image 
[image]

Exported csv image

[image]

I was wondering whether this is an application related issue or is it something wrong in general.

Did anyone face the same issue ?  I do not have idea about where to begin to solve the styling issue. Some pointer will be greatly appreciated.

I added apache poi tag because I created the original excel using apache-poi

Comment: CSV files contain no formatting - they're exactly as the name implies, a list of values, separated by commas.

Comment: Just repeating what @Olly said.  To open in different apps it must only be a list of data - the Mac OS Numbers app wouldn't have a clue about Excel formatting so including any extra info would just fubar it all.

Comment: Use Google Sheets :)

Comment: Thanks all of you for valuable input

Answer (score 2):

CSV stands for "Comma Separated Value".

CSV is a text file. Basically, you can open it with Excel or with a basic text editor. It is not made for storing formatting.

If you need to deal with formatted table then you have to choose another format.